# How to change NativeBase button color

Tags: react-native, user-interface, mobile, expo, native-base

So I'm trying to make a Toggle button using NativeBase button. I'm struggling with color settings.

- Variants

  Selected: purple('#9747FF') background&outline, white text,

  unSelected: white background, purple('#9747FF') text, lightgray outline

**Current code**

````
<HStack space={2}>
<Button
    variant={selectedGender === 'male' ? 'solid' : 'outline'}
    outlineColor="#9747FF"
    colorScheme={selectedGender === 'male' ? '#9747FF' : 'white'}
    onPress={() => handleGenderSelect('male')}
    _text={{ color: selectedGender === 'male' ? 'white' : '#9747FF' }}
>
    남성
</Button>
<Button
    variant={selectedGender === 'female' ? 'solid' : 'outline'}
    outlineColor="#9747FF"
    colorScheme={selectedGender === 'female' ? '#9747FF' : 'white'}
    onPress={() => handleGenderSelect('female')}
    _text={{ color: selectedGender === 'female' ? 'white' : '#9747FF' }}
>
    여성
</Button>
</HStack>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `style` to override the [default theme](https://docs.nativebase.io/next/default-theme). Something like this:

```
<Button
  variant={selectedGender === 'male' ? 'solid' : 'outline'}
  style={{
    backgroundColor: selectedGender === 'male' ? '#9747FF' : 'white',
    borderColor: '#9747FF',
  }}
  onPress={() => handleGenderSelect('male')}
  _text={{ color: selectedGender === 'male' ? 'white' : '#9747FF' }}>
  Male
</Button>
```

Another way is to [customize components](https://docs.nativebase.io/next/customizing-components) by extending the theme.